# Share code between classes

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a simple function like this:

```
public static string randomthing(string var1) 
{
    string var2 = "hello world";
    return var2;
}
```

I would like to be able to call it from different classes. How can I do it?

I tried to create a blank file and just paste the function there but of course it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to share code, you need to create a third class that can be used by the other classes.

This can be done as an extension method, a static class or regular class (meaning you need an instance of the class).

Static class:

```
public static MyClass
{
    public static string randomthing(string var1) {

        string var2 = "hello world";
        return var2;
    }
}

// Call it: MyClass.randomthing("a string");
```

Extension method:

```
public MyClass
{
    public static string randomthing(this string var1) {

        string var2 = "hello world";
        return var2;
    }
}

// Call it: "a string".randomthing();
```

Regular class:

```
public static MyClass
{
    public static string randomthing(string var1) {

        string var2 = "hello world";
        return var2;
    }
}

// Call it: var myClass = new myClass(); 
//          myClass.randomthing("a string");
```

Comment: The class in which your extension method resides needs to be static as well.

Answer (score 4):

A method can only be part of a class.  So declare it inside of a class(or a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), which can be static when it's just a collection of static methods:

```
class RandomThings
{
    public static string randomthing(string var1) {
        string var2 = "hello world";
        return var2;
     } 
}
```

Now you can call this method via `ClassName.MethodName`:

```
String randomString = RandomThings.randomthing("hello world");
```

[Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the class static and call it from another class without having to instantiate the class itself.

```
public static class Utility {
    public static string randomthing(string var1) {

                string var2 = "hello world";

                return var2;

    }
}

public class UsingTheCodeHere
{

    public string SayingHelloWorld()
    {
        return Utility.randomthing();
    }

}
```

You can also achieve something similar using inheritance.

```
public class Person 
{
     public string SayHello()
     {
         return "Hello"; 
     }
}

public class LoudMouth : Person
{
    public override string SayHello()
    {
        return base.SayHello() + "!!!!";
    }
}

public class SadPerson : Person
{
    public override string SayHello()
    {
        return base.SayHello() + " I am sad";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), just call it by using the enclosed class name:

```
public class Foo
{
   public static string randomthing(string var1)
   {
      string var2 = "hello world";
      return var2;
   }
}

public class OtherClass
{  
    public OtherClass()
    {
       // In constructor
       string here1 = Foo.randomthing("x");
    }

    public void OrInSomeFunction()
    {
       string here2 = Foo.randomthing("x");
    }
}
```